# Does train function of the caret package split the data?

Tags: r, cross-validation, caret

I am trying to predict emotion from facial action unit codings using a cross-validation approach, so training the model on 70% of the data and then letting it predict the remaining 30%. I am doing this in R with the caret package.

Here's my code:

```
# Splitting the data into train and test
index <- createDataPartition(GF_scope_pred_emo$emotion, p = .70, list = FALSE)
train <- GF_scope_pred_emo[index, ]
test <- GF_scope_pred_emo[-index, ]

# Setting the reference
train$emotion <- as.factor(train$emotion)
train$emotion <- relevel(train$emotion, ref = "anger")

# Training the multinomial model
train_control <- trainControl(method='cv',number=10)
GF_pred_emo_model <- caret::train(emotion ~ ., data = train, method = 'multinom', trControl = train_control)
```

What I am confused about is whether to use the train data set for the data argument in the train function (as is done here) or the whole data set (which would be GF_scope_pred_emo in this case). In other words, is the part where I split the data even necessary or does caret's train function split the data internally and I now "double split" it. I find both ways on the internet hence my confusion.